# How to parse this json.dumps from a http response and access each value?

Tags: python, json

### Code:

```py
import requests
import json

subscription_key = "2d18be7f5f3c4e24a426d696e4a66e85"
assert subscription_key

emotion_recognition_url = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect"

header = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

params = {'returnFaceId': 'true',
          'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
          'returnFaceAttributes':'emotion'}

image_path = r"C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\sad.jpg"
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()


headers  = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
response = requests.post(emotion_recognition_url,
                         params=params,
                         headers=headers,
                         data=image_data)
print(json.dumps(response.json()))
if response.status_code == 202:
    print ("pass through")
else:
    response.raise_for_status()
```

### Output:

```
[{'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.739,
                                 'contempt': 0.002,
                                 'disgust': 0.122,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.136,
                                 'sadness': 0.0,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '176613df-b4ff-47fd-8d36-696b96fcc1cb',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 307, 'left': 95, 'top': 105, 'width': 307}}]
```

I get this response and I am using python.
I want to access each value like anger, contempt, sadness, etc and convert them in integer.
The response is in  i checked it using print(type(values))
I tried using pandas and normalize but nothing worked.
can anyone plz help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `pandas`:

- If you only have one image, this is overkill
- This is a better option if you have multiple images and the JSON response is a list of many dicts
- It doesn't seem like the api can process multiple images at once, so a loop has been added to iterate through multiple images

  - Each image response is appended to the `data` list
  - The file path is added to the for each face
  - Some images may not process because of image quality.  These still get a 200 response but an empty list.  This is handled by adding only the file path to data
- After all images are processed, use `json_normalize` on `data`
- The question asked how to process `json.dumps(response.json())`.  `response.json()` is a `list` of `dicts` (e.g. `[{}]`).  `json.dumps` turns that into a `str` (e.g. `'[{}]'`), which makes that data more difficult to process.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pathlib import Path
import requests

subscription_key = "2d18be7f5f3c4e24a426d696e4a66e85"
assert subscription_key

emotion_recognition_url = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect"

header = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

params = {'returnFaceId': 'true',
          'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
          'returnFaceAttributes':'emotion'}

# Use pathlib to set path to multiple images
p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_files\data\sad')
# list of all images in dir (use rglob to get subdirectories)
f = list(p.glob('*.jpg'))

data = list()

# iterate through images
for face in f:

    image_data = face.open('rb').read()
    headers  = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}

    response = requests.post(emotion_recognition_url,
                             params=params,
                             headers=headers,
                             data=image_data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # parse respone
        data_list = response.json()

        # chcck if the list is empty - happens if api can't process face
        if data_list:
            data_dict = data_list[0]
            # add the file path to dict so you know which is processed
            data_dict['file'] = str(face)
            data.append(data_dict)
        else:
            # add unprocessed face
            data.append({'file': str(face)})
    else:
        response.raise_for_status()

df = json_normalize(data)
```

#### `df` output:

```py
                                 faceId                                                     file  faceRectangle.top  faceRectangle.left  faceRectangle.width  faceRectangle.height  faceAttributes.emotion.anger  faceAttributes.emotion.contempt  faceAttributes.emotion.disgust  faceAttributes.emotion.fear  faceAttributes.emotion.happiness  faceAttributes.emotion.neutral  faceAttributes.emotion.sadness  faceAttributes.emotion.surprise
0  430ca5d7-7ec8-41d8-9bbe-466dc4f4894b   E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face.jpg               49.0                87.0                 91.0                  91.0                         0.000                            0.000                           0.000                        0.000                             0.000                           0.999                           0.001                            0.000
1  0db74fa5-32ee-4c59-9c5c-a5cbc82432f6  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face1.jpg                0.0                86.0                168.0                 160.0                         0.001                            0.004                           0.000                        0.000                             0.000                           0.511                           0.485                            0.000
2                                   NaN  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face2.jpg                NaN                 NaN                  NaN                   NaN                           NaN                              NaN                             NaN                          NaN                               NaN                             NaN                             NaN                              NaN
3  9e91a58e-f229-4932-b3d2-90ec5885be7d  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face3.jpg               31.0                24.0                157.0                 190.0                         0.002                            0.015                           0.000                        0.000                             0.005                           0.855                           0.122                            0.000
4  8096041e-a490-463a-8fa6-343f756bd19a  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face4.jpg               58.0                95.0                104.0                 104.0                         0.000                            0.000                           0.000                        0.000                             0.000                           0.249                           0.750                            0.000
5  d2da0dba-efce-46a3-be78-47bedf3a7a38  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face5.jpg               41.0                18.0                163.0                 163.0                         0.000                            0.000                           0.001                        0.063                             0.000                           0.063                           0.872                            0.001
6  5bcb28fa-0d28-46a6-8145-7e9ad4ee9316  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face6.jpg               21.0                58.0                159.0                 159.0                         0.004                            0.006                           0.000                        0.000                             0.002                           0.944                           0.043                            0.000
7  160fae25-56cd-483f-b7ce-2f74891c75a3  E:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\data\sad\sad_face7.jpg                6.0                 0.0                182.0                 228.0                         0.001                            0.007                           0.000                        0.000                             0.000                           0.321                           0.671                            0.000
```

#### `data`:

- In this case, `data` is a `list` of `dicts`

```py
[{'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.0,
                                 'contempt': 0.0,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.999,
                                 'sadness': 0.001,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '430ca5d7-7ec8-41d8-9bbe-466dc4f4894b',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 91, 'left': 87, 'top': 49, 'width': 91},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.001,
                                 'contempt': 0.004,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.511,
                                 'sadness': 0.485,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '0db74fa5-32ee-4c59-9c5c-a5cbc82432f6',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 160, 'left': 86, 'top': 0, 'width': 168},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face1.jpg'},
 {'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face2.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.002,
                                 'contempt': 0.015,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.005,
                                 'neutral': 0.855,
                                 'sadness': 0.122,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '9e91a58e-f229-4932-b3d2-90ec5885be7d',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 190, 'left': 24, 'top': 31, 'width': 157},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face3.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.0,
                                 'contempt': 0.0,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.249,
                                 'sadness': 0.75,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '8096041e-a490-463a-8fa6-343f756bd19a',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 104, 'left': 95, 'top': 58, 'width': 104},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face4.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.0,
                                 'contempt': 0.0,
                                 'disgust': 0.001,
                                 'fear': 0.063,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.063,
                                 'sadness': 0.872,
                                 'surprise': 0.001}},
  'faceId': 'd2da0dba-efce-46a3-be78-47bedf3a7a38',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 163, 'left': 18, 'top': 41, 'width': 163},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face5.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.004,
                                 'contempt': 0.006,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.002,
                                 'neutral': 0.944,
                                 'sadness': 0.043,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '5bcb28fa-0d28-46a6-8145-7e9ad4ee9316',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 159, 'left': 58, 'top': 21, 'width': 159},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face6.jpg'},
 {'faceAttributes': {'emotion': {'anger': 0.001,
                                 'contempt': 0.007,
                                 'disgust': 0.0,
                                 'fear': 0.0,
                                 'happiness': 0.0,
                                 'neutral': 0.321,
                                 'sadness': 0.671,
                                 'surprise': 0.0}},
  'faceId': '160fae25-56cd-483f-b7ce-2f74891c75a3',
  'faceRectangle': {'height': 228, 'left': 0, 'top': 6, 'width': 182},
  'file': 'E:\\PythonProjects\\stack_overflow\\data\\sad\\sad_face7.jpg'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is a list, you just need to get the first element of the list which contains the data you want.

`response.json()[0].get('anger')`

[See here for examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)